# How to run port 443 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 I can setup tomcat 9 to run https://abc:8443 but cannot run on https:abc using default port of 443 for https.

I created the certificate and setup tomcat9 to run https://abc:8443.

In Tomcat9/conf/server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   redirectPort="443" />
        <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                   maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="/home/alam/certificate/aaa" keystorePass="changeit">
```

I hoping to be able to run tomcat9 on url https:abc The default port for https should be 443.

I used :sudo systemctl restart tomcat I am getting the following error in the tomcat log:

> 08-Oct-2019 16:15:50.105 SEVERE [main]
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed
>   to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-443]]
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler
>   initialization failed at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:983)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:533)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1059)
>   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
>   at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:584) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:607) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:304) at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474) Caused
>   by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
>   at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>   at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:230)
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:213)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1124)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1137)
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:574)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
>   ... 13 more

Comment: Have you run `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` to open the port on your firewall?

Comment: I think the error prior to the one you posted says why it couldn't bind.

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/889122/how-to-get-tomcat-9-to-work-with-authbind-to-bind-to-port-80
Has information on using `authbind` to use ports <1024 as non-root users.